# postgressql temp table join query is giving column "p1.average_price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Below was my query:

```
select p1.* from price_temp p1
inner join (select p2.id, p2.program_id, MIN(p2.price) min_price from price_temp p2
            right outer join report_drugs on report_drugs.price_id = p2.id
            where report_drugs.report_id = '489' and p2.drug_details_id='293468'
            group by p2.id, p2.program_id) p
on p.program_id=p1.program_id and p.id=p1.id
where p1.price=p.min_price
group by p1.id,p1.program_id
order by p1.price,p1.program_id;
```

this was working with the main table(price) but with my temp table(temp_price) it is throwing exceptions "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function " for each column

below is my query for inserting data in a temporary table

```
select * into temp price_temp from price where createdat > (current_date - interval  '6 days')
```

please guide

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is  `price.id` the primary key? If yes, you either need to define `price_temp.id` as the primary key as well (or at least a unique key). Or include all columns in the `group by` as the error message suggests

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name is there a way to add primary key to select into query!!

Comment: @SaiDeekshita: you don't add the primary key to the query, but to the table, like `create unique index price_idx on  price_temp(id)` .